# Color in Google's Timeline Chart bars based in the a specific value

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to create groups of colors for the bars. The example below is raw. I would like to add a column with a category type, and based on that category I will color the bar.

Something like:

**Column**

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
```

**Line**

```
[ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00001', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
[ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00002', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
[ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
[ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryB', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
[ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00004', new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
[ 'GROUP #2', 'CategoryC', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
[ 'GROUP #3', 'CategoryC', 'C00006', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
[ 'GROUP #4', 'CategoryA', 'C00007', new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]]);
```

Based on Category the bar should have a specific color.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/e5hWp/)

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["timeline"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00001', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00002', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00004', new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #2', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #3', 'C00006', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #4', 'C00007', new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]]);

    var rowHeight = 41;
    var chartHeight = (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() + 1) * rowHeight;

    var options = {
        timeline: { 
            groupByRowLabel: true,
            rowLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14,
                color: '#333333'
            },
            barLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        },                          
        avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
        height: chartHeight,
        width: '100%'
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's nothing in the Timeline visualization that will do this for you, but you can set the `colors` option to whatever you need to get the bars the right color.  You can parse the DataTable to build the colors array, and then use a DataView to hide your category column from the Timeline (since the Timeline wouldn't know what to do with it).  Here's an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00001', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00002', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryB', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00004', new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #2', 'CategoryC', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #3', 'CategoryC', 'C00006', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #4', 'CategoryA', 'C00007', new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]
    ]);

    var colors = [];
    var colorMap = {
        // should contain a map of category -> color for every category
        CategoryA: '#e63b6f',
        CategoryB: '#19c362',
        CategoryC: '#592df7'
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1)]);
    }

    var rowHeight = 41;
    var chartHeight = (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() + 1) * rowHeight;

    var options = {
        timeline: { 
            groupByRowLabel: true,
            rowLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14,
                color: '#333333'
            },
            barLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        },                          
        avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
        height: chartHeight,
        width: '100%',
        colors: colors
    };

    // use a DataView to hide the category column from the Timeline
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    view.setColumns([0, 2, 3, 4]);

    chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7A88H/

Comment: this no longer works in the latest version as of Sept 1 2016 :(

Comment: No, it doesn't. Even the fiddle doesn't work anymore. Sure the colors are there, but if you look at the source you will see that those are different colors that should be shown. You can, however, now use 'style' column and control column with that.

Comment: Seems like it does not work for some cases where you have overlapping intervals.

Comment: @KarthikSWOT this answer is 5 years old; it is quite possible that the developers made breaking changes to the API over that time. I have not been using the Visualization API for many years now, so I suggest you open a new question about how to do this with the modern version.

Answer (score 19):

Use the undocumented 'style' role as seen in my working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/af8jq9aa/1/

```
function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('example5.4');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'red/green/blue', 'NAME OF BAR (should be RED) (ff0000)', '#ff0000', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3) ],
    [ 'red/green/blue', 'NAME OF BAR (should be GREEN) (00ff00)','#00ff00', new Date(1796, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3) ],
    [ 'red/green/blue', 'NAME OF BAR (should be BLUE) (0000ff)','#0000ff',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3) ]]);

  var options = {
  };

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: This approach was necessary for situations where series grouped in a single row overlap. The `options.colors` approach only seems to work on series drawn at the top of their row. Also, it seems that if a `view` is used to draw the chart, the style column must be included in the view at the same position that it exists in the `dataTable`.

Comment: Has anyone tried this in the current version? It doesn't seem to be working to me

Comment: @EmilioSG - I tried this Jul 19, 2022 and it worked for me. Did you remember the `addColumn` for `role: 'style'`? Add it just before the dates.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried something like this and it worked and was able to set different colors to different row labels in the grid.

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ShiftDetails' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'RowDetails' });
dataTable.addRows([['APHANEE WORARUCHEE','','',new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),new 
Date(0,0,0,18,0,0),'asdf'],
['CHEW SEOW LEE','','',new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),new Date(0,0,0,9,0,0),'qwerty'],['TOTAL 
MANPOWER PER HOUR','5','color: red',new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0),new 
Date(0,0,0,1,0,0),'TOTAL'], 
['TOTAL MANPOWER PER HOUR','4','color: red',new Date(0,0,0,1,0,0),new 
Date(0,0,0,2,0,0),'TOTAL']]);

var options = {
timeline: { singleColor: '#8d8', barLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Arial Black', fontSize: 
12 } },backgroundColor: '#ffd'};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the role style on the middle of the array. it **must** be on the middle for it to work. I have tried pushing it on the end of my array and it did not work.

```
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });      <===========
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
}
```

Comment: Never thought the position of the style column would matter. Couldn't figure out why my style column wasn't working! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I did like this, its working fine for me.

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'JobType' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

for (var j = 0; j < model.JobType.length; j++)
{
    var jbt = model.JobType;
    var ColorValue = null;

    if (jbt == "Job A"){
        ColorValue = "#AF0BEA";
    }
    else if (jbt == "Job B")
    {
        ColorValue = "#19c362";
    }
    else if (jbt == "Job C")
    {
        ColorValue = "#091F8B";
    }
    else if (jbt == "Job D")
    {
        ColorValue = "#592df7";
    }
    else if (jbt == "Job E")
    {
        ColorValue = "#d3401b";
    }

    dataTable.addRows([[name, jbt, ColorValue, startdate, endDate]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use option:

```
    timeline: {
        colorByRowLabel: true
    }
```

From google docs: **timeline.colorByRowLabel**  default value boolean   false
*If set to true, colors every bar on the row the same. The default is to use one color per bar label.*

Comment: You right, but my example wasn't right. I just updated it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set fixed colors
var colors = [];
var colorMap = {
  'Maschine in Produktion':                       '#7baaf7',
  'Behälterwechsel':                              '#e67c73',
  'Auftragsgemäßes Rüsten von W.Z. und Material': '#f7cb4d',
  'Unterbrechung':                                '#57ba8a',
  'neues Werkzeug einfahren':                     '#c47ed0',
  'Produktqualität(vermessen der Teile)':         '#4dc5d4',
  'frei':                                         '#ff9b7b',
  'Werkzeugschaden':                              '#bbba66',
  'Coilmaterial (nicht geeignet)':                '#8d97d3',
  'neues Werkzeug einfahren':                     '#f5cfff'
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {      
  colors.push(colorMap[data.getValue(i, 0)]);
}

var unique = colors.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
  return i == colors.indexOf(itm);
});


var options = {
  height:   800, 
  hAxis:        {format: isDay == 1 ? 'HH:MM:SS' : 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM:SS'},
  tooltip:  {isHtml: true},
  legend:   'none',
  avoidOverlappingGridLines: false,
  colors:   unique
};

chart.draw(data, options);
```

This works perfectly for me. The main Problem with the old code is, that the colors array....is just an array and not a unique Hashmap. You can just use the custom filter function in order to get the unique colors.