# Setting colors for google visualization timeline not linked to dataTable rows

Tags: google-visualization, timeline

I have been having a lot of issues with coloring individual elements of a google visualization timeline object. I have tried ordering my colors[] object different ways, but it seems the current google visualization library processes the colors based on a horizontal-first approach to parsing the dates, but as I never know exactly how the dates will get arranged in the timeline, I cannot predict the color ordering.

I found a decent example of this in a previous post on Stack Overflow [23268616](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268616/color-in-googles-timeline-chart-bars-based-in-the-a-specific-value).  The JSFiddle referenced on that page doesn't actually work for me (using Chrome 49.0.2623.87) with the current Google Visualization package. I also tried Firefox and get the same incorrect results.

Fiddle replicated here for reference:

```js
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00001', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00002', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryB', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00004', new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #2', 'CategoryC', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #3', 'CategoryC', 'C00006', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #4', 'CategoryA', 'C00007', new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]
    ]);

    var colors = [];
    var colorMap = {
        // should contain a map of category -> color for every category
        CategoryA: '#e63b6f',
        CategoryB: '#19c362',
        CategoryC: '#592df7'
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1)]);
    }

    var rowHeight = 41;
    var chartHeight = (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() + 1) * rowHeight;

    var options = {
        timeline: { 
            groupByRowLabel: true,
            rowLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14,
                color: '#333333'
            },
            barLabelStyle: {
                fontName: 'Roboto Condensed',
                fontSize: 14
            }
        },                          
        avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
        height: chartHeight,
        width: '100%',
        colors: colors
    };

    // use a DataView to hide the category column from the Timeline
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    view.setColumns([0, 2, 3, 4]);

    chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?.js"></script>
<div id='example4.2'></div>
```

For example, in this code, according to the colormap, line C00004 is supposed to be category A, but in my browser it is colored like category B! C0007 is supposed to be category A as well, but is category C In color! I cannot even figure out the pattern which is coloring the objects the way it is. Re-arranging the addRows([]) list leads to more crazy results... is this feature of Google Visualization just plain broken?
I have also tried referencing the library via https://www.gstatic.com/charts.loader.js but get the same results.

Comment: had the same results, tried using [style column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) as well, no luck...