# Color google timeline chart bars one particular color, and make others 'default' assorted colors

Tags: javascript, charts, colors, google-visualization, timeline

I have some bars on a google timeline chart that are specified as 'CategoryB' that I want colored let's say black/#000 for this example.

For all others I can make them a *particular* color of my choosing, but I don't want to specify - I'd prefer that they're given the default random colors that google gives them so they're all a bit different.

Is there a way to specify 'color: 'default'' or similar for 'CategoryA'? I've edited some code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268616/color-in-googles-timeline-chart-bars-based-in-the-a-specific-value) question - you'll see near the bottom are the two colors.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhr1o79t/)

Javascript:

```
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Category' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00001', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00002', new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryB', 'C00003', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryB', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 0, 22),  new Date(2014, 2, 18) ],
        [ 'GROUP #1', 'CategoryA', 'C00004', new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #2', 'CategoryA', 'C00005', new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #3', 'CategoryB', 'C00006', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
        [ 'GROUP #4', 'CategoryA', 'C00007', new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]
    ]);
    
    var colors = [];
    var colorMap = {
        // should contain a map of category -> color for every category
        CategoryA: '#e63b6f',
        CategoryB: '#000',
        
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1)]);
    }
    
    var rowHeight = 41;
    var chartHeight = (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() + 1) * rowHeight;
    
    var options = {
        timeline: { 
            groupByRowLabel: true,
            
        },                          
        avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
        height: chartHeight,
        width: '100%',
        colors: colors
    };
    
    // use a DataView to hide the category column from the Timeline
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    view.setColumns([0, 2, 3, 4]);
    
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

Html:

```
<div id='example4.2'></div>
```

Comment: Why isn't storing the value of this color in a variable and then using it an option? @JackNapier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, the version of google charts you are loading has been deprecated.
the `jsapi` load should no longer be used.
according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes), we should use the following `gstatic` loader from now on...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement.
in this case, recommend using...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

---

next, we can use the style role to add the color directly to the data table.
and we can remove the category column currently used to determine the color.

note: the style role must be the third column to work properly.

for the `'CategoryB'` rows, we set the color to black.
for the remaining rows, we use `null` as the color value.
google will then use the default colors for those rows, as desired.

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });  // <-- style role
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00001', null, new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00002', null, new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', null, new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', '#000000', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00005', '#000000', new Date(2014, 0, 22),  new Date(2014, 2, 18) ],
    [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00004', null, new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
    [ 'GROUP #2', 'C00005', null, new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
    [ 'GROUP #3', 'C00006', '#000000', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
    [ 'GROUP #4', 'C00007', null, new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]
]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('example4.2');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Group' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'ID' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00001', null, new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 31) ],
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00002', null, new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 28) ],
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', null, new Date(2014, 3, 1),  new Date(2014, 3, 15) ],
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00003', '#000000', new Date(2014, 0, 21),  new Date(2014, 2, 19) ],
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00005', '#000000', new Date(2014, 0, 22),  new Date(2014, 2, 18) ],
      [ 'GROUP #1', 'C00004', null, new Date(2014, 0, 1),  new Date(2014, 0, 15) ],
      [ 'GROUP #2', 'C00005', null, new Date(2014, 2, 8),  new Date(2014, 2, 15) ],
      [ 'GROUP #3', 'C00006', '#000000', new Date(2014, 5, 1),  new Date(2014, 5, 15) ],
      [ 'GROUP #4', 'C00007', null, new Date(2014, 1, 15),  new Date(2014, 1, 25) ]
  ]);

  var rowHeight = 41;
  var chartHeight = (dataTable.getNumberOfRows() + 1) * rowHeight;

  var options = {
      timeline: {
        groupByRowLabel: true,
      },
      avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
      height: chartHeight,
      width: '100%'
  };

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="example4.2"></div>
```

Comment: Stunning answer and so much simpler than categories etc! Thank you so much. Can I ask - why must style be the third column?

Comment: cheers! not sure exactly, according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#data-format), the third position is used for custom tooltips. and the style role only started working on the timeline in recent versions. and would not have worked when the question you referenced was answered. anyway, I've tested several scenarios, if you remove the bar label in the second position, the style role will not work.